# How to use Google Places API for android?

Tags: android, google-places-api

I'd like to use Google Placese API by using 'name' in Android.

but I can't find searching way to use by name in android and just found way to use types..

For example,

```
types=cafe|bakery
```

But, I want to use names not types.

In other words, I want to use name such as A store, B cafe.. so on.

Is there anyone who know way to use venue's name in Android?

I really really want to get answer.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Use name or keyword parameters

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search?hl=en

Comment: above I attached a part of my code, could you check how to modify that code?